# Animate transitions between destinations in navigation

Tags: android, navigation

How can I animate transitions between destinations in navigation?

This is how I move on to the next fragment

```
Handler().postDelayed({
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_food_text_analysis,null)
        },6000)
```

thees are two animation xml files

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration = "1000"/>

</set>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration = "1000"/>

</set>
```

this is my navigation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/welcome_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_food_text_analysis"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.foodTextAnalysis.FoodAnalysisFragment"
        android:label="Food analysis"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_food_text_analysis" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_recipe_analysis"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.recipeAnalysis.RecipeAnalysis"
        android:label="Recipe analysis"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recipe_analysis" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/welcome_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreen"
        android:label="welcome screen"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_welcome_screen" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_welcome_fragment_to_nav_food_text_analysis2"
            app:destination="@id/nav_food_text_analysis"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/fragment_open_exit" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I need it to be like this
 [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCDtX.gif)

I got the result I need with this code

```
      Handler().postDelayed({
      (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.anim.enter_from_right,
                    R.anim.exit_to_right
                )
                .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, FoodAnalysisFragment())
                .commit()
        },6000)
```

but now I need to use the navigation to switch fragments
Help me pleas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `navigate(R.id.nav_food_text_analysis, null)` - using the destination ID directly, which means no animations are run.

You'd want to use `navigate(R.id.action_welcome_fragment_to_nav_food_text_analysis2, null)` if you want to navigate via your action and run the `enterAnim` and `exitAnim` associated with that action.

Comment: it helped me. Thank you so much. Do you know how to make it so that after switching a fragment I can no longer return to the previous fragment? The previous fragment is the welcome screen, I think it makes no sense to return to it when I press the back arrow

Comment: You shouldn't be using a welcome screen as your start destination in the first place as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) and the [Conditional Navigation guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional)

Comment: so what is the best way to make a welcome screen? use another fragment as the start screen and then check if the welcome screen has not been launched, then start it and after that switch to the fragment that is marked as the start screen?